# Strange issue with Bluetooth connectivity in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a requirement of connecting to a bluetooth scanner from my android application. After it is connected the scanned RFID's will be added to local database.

The problem here is that the bluetooth scanner does not connect at times not sure when it fails to connect as there is no definite pattern to fail.

And at times it connects but does not read any RFID's. cannot figure out whay it fails. I only get one exception message

```
"read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1"
```

Here is the code of BluetoothDeviceConnector:

```
public class BluetoothDeviceConnector : IDeviceConnector
{
    private const string Tag = nameof(BluetoothDeviceConnector);

    private const int StateNone = 0; // we're doing nothing
    private const int StateConnecting = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    private const int StateConnected = 3; // now connected to a remote device

    protected readonly BluetoothAdapter BluetoothAdapter;
    private readonly IMessageHandler _handler;
    private readonly string _mAddress;
    private ConnectThread _mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread _mConnectedThread;
    private int _mState;
    private readonly ILog _log;

    ///<summary>
    /// Prepare a new Bluetooth session.
    /// @param handler A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
    ///</summary>

    public BluetoothDeviceConnector(IMessageHandler handler, string address, ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;
        BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
        _mState = StateNone;
        _handler = handler;
        _mAddress = address;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the current state of the connection
    /// @param state An integer defining the current connection state
    /// </summary>

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    private void SetState(int state)
    {
        _log.Info(Tag + " setState() " + _mState + " -> " + state);
        _mState = state;
    }

    private BluetoothAdapter GetBluetoothAdapter()
    {
        return BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public void Connect()
    {
        var device = GetBluetoothAdapter().GetRemoteDevice(_mAddress);
        Connect(device);
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
    /// @param device The BluetoothDevice to connect
    /// </summary>

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public void Connect(BluetoothDevice device)
    {
        _log.Info(Tag + " connecting to: " + device);

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (_mState == StateConnecting)
        {
            if (_mConnectThread != null)
            {
                _mConnectThread.Cancel();
                _mConnectThread = null;
            }
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (_mConnectedThread != null)
        {
            _mConnectedThread.Cancel();
            _mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        try
        {
            _mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, this);
            _mConnectThread.Start();
            SetState(StateConnecting);
            _handler.SendConnectingTo(device.Name);
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {

            _log.Error(Tag + " Connect(BluetoothDevice device) :", e);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            _log.Error(Tag + " Connect(BluetoothDevice device) :", e);
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
        {
            _log.Error(Tag + " Connect(BluetoothDevice device) :", e);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            _log.Error(Tag + " Connect(BluetoothDevice device) :", e);
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException e)
        {
            _log.Error(Tag + " Connect(BluetoothDevice device) :", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _log.Error(Tag + " Connect(BluetoothDevice device) :", e);
        }
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
    /// @param socket The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
    /// @param device The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
    /// </summary>

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public void Connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device)
    {
        _log.Info(Tag + " connected");

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (_mConnectThread != null)
        {
            _mConnectThread.Cancel();
            _mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (_mConnectedThread != null)
        {
            _mConnectedThread.Cancel();
            _mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        _mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, this);
        _mConnectedThread.Start();

        SetState(StateConnected);
        _handler.SendConnectedTo(device.Name);
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Stop all threads
    /// </summary>

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public void Disconnect()
    {
        _log.Info(Tag + " Disconnect");

        if (_mConnectThread != null)
        {
            _mConnectThread.Cancel();
            _mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if (_mConnectedThread != null)
        {
            _mConnectedThread.Shutdown();
            _mConnectedThread.Cancel();
            _mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        SetState(StateNone);
        _handler.SendNotConnected();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public void SendAsciiMessage(string chars)
    {
        //Write((chars + "\n").GetBytes());
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
    /// @param out The bytes to write
    /// @see ConnectedThread#Write(byte[])
    /// </summary>

    private void Write(byte[] value)
    {
        // Create temporary object

        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        if (_mState != StateConnected) return;

        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _mConnectedThread.Write(value);
        });
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
    /// </summary>
    private void ConnectionFailed()
    {
        SetState(StateNone);
        _handler.SendConnectionFailed();
        _log.Info(Tag + " ConnectionFailed");
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
    /// </summary>

    private void ConnectionLost()
    {
        SetState(StateNone);
        _handler.SendConnectionLost();
        _log.Info(Tag + " ConnectionLost");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
    /// with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
    /// succeeds or fails.
    /// SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException
    /// </summary>
    private class ConnectThread : Thread
    {
        private readonly BluetoothSocket _mmSocket;
        private readonly BluetoothDevice _mmDevice;
        private readonly BluetoothDeviceConnector _deviceConnector;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, BluetoothDeviceConnector deviceConnector)
        {
            _mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            _deviceConnector = deviceConnector;

            _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " calling device.createRfcommSocket with channel 1 ...");
            try
            {
                //tmp = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
                //tmp = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device.GetUuids()[0].Uuid);
                deviceConnector.BluetoothAdapter.CancelDiscovery();
                var createRfcommSocket = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(device.Class.Handle, "createInsecureRfcommSocket", "(I)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket;");
                var socket = JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(device.Handle, createRfcommSocket, new JValue(1));
                tmp = GetObject<BluetoothSocket>(socket, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
                _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " calling device.createRfcommSocket with channel 2 ...");
                var uuidList = device.GetUuids();
                if (uuidList != null)
                {
                    foreach (var uuid in uuidList)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " connect with uuid: " + uuid);
                            tmp = device.CreateInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid.Uuid);
                            tmp.Connect();
                            _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " connect with uuid status: " + tmp.IsConnected);
                            if (tmp.IsConnected)
                            {
                                _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " uuid success " + uuid);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            // ignored
                        }
                    }
                }

                _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " setting socket to result of createRfcommSocket");
                _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " setting socket Status" + tmp.IsConnected);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _deviceConnector._log.Error(Tag + " ConnectThread", e);
            }
            _mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public override void Run()
        {
            base.Run();
            _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " BEGIN mConnectThread");
            //setName("ConnectThread");

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            _deviceConnector.BluetoothAdapter.CancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try
            {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " Run() => " + _mmSocket.IsConnected);
                if (!_deviceConnector.BluetoothAdapter.IsDiscovering && !_mmSocket.IsConnected)
                {
                    _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " BEGIN mConnectThread 1");
                    _mmSocket.Connect();
                    _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " BEGIN mConnectThread 2");
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                _deviceConnector._log.Error(Tag + " ConnectThread => Run Function", e);
                _deviceConnector.ConnectionFailed();
                try
                {
                    _mmSocket.Close();
                }
                catch (IOException e2)
                {
                    _deviceConnector._log.Error(Tag + " unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            _deviceConnector._mConnectThread = null;

            // Start the connected thread
            _deviceConnector.Connected(_mmSocket, _mmDevice);
            _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " END mConnectThread");
        }

        [Obsolete("deprecated")]
        public override void Destroy()
        {
            try
            {
                _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " Destory()");
                _mmSocket?.Close();
                _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " Destroy");
                base.Destroy();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                _deviceConnector._log.Error(Tag + " close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }

        public void Cancel()
        {
            try
            {
                _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " Cancel()");
                _mmSocket?.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                _deviceConnector._log.Error(Tag + " close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
    /// It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
    /// </summary>
    private class ConnectedThread : Thread
    {
        private readonly BluetoothSocket _mmSocket;
        private readonly Stream _mmInStream;
        private readonly Stream _mmOutStream;
        private readonly BluetoothDeviceConnector _deviceConnector;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDeviceConnector deviceConnector)
        {
            _deviceConnector = deviceConnector;
            _mmSocket = socket;
            _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " create ConnectedThread");
            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try
            {
                _mmInStream = _mmSocket?.InputStream;
                _mmOutStream = _mmSocket?.OutputStream;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                _deviceConnector._log.Error(Tag + " temp sockets not created", e);
            }
        }

        private bool _stop;
        private readonly bool _hasReadAnything = false;

        public void Shutdown()
        {
            _stop = true;
            if (!_hasReadAnything) return;

            try
            {
                _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " Shutdown ConnectedThread");
                _mmInStream?.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                _deviceConnector._log.Error(Tag + " close() of InputStream failed.", e);
            }
        }

        public override void Run()
        {
            base.Run();
            _deviceConnector._log.Info(Tag + " BEGIN mConnectedThread");

            var reader = new Java.IO.BufferedReader(new Java.IO.InputStreamReader(_mmInStream));

            while (!_stop)
            {
                try
                {
                    var rfid = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rfid?.Trim()))
                    {
                        _deviceConnector._handler.SendLineRead(rfid);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    _deviceConnector._log.Error(Tag + " disconnected", e);
                    _deviceConnector.ConnectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        ///<summary>
        /// Write to the connected OutStream.
        /// @param bytes The bytes to write
        /// </summary>

        public void Write(byte[] bytes)
        {
            try
            {
                _mmOutStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                _deviceConnector._handler.SendBytesWritten(bytes);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                _deviceConnector._log.Error(Tag + " Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void Cancel()
        {
            try
            {
                _deviceConnector._log.Error(Tag + " ConnectedThread() => Cancel()");
                _mmSocket?.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                _deviceConnector._log.Error(Tag + " close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody please help me in figuring the issue, as the main function of the app I am working on is to connect to scanner and scan the RFID's.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `tmp = device.CreateInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid.Uuid);`  to   `tmp = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid.Uuid);`

Comment: Didn't help! :-(

Comment: Do you have any guesses on why it could be happening?